# Firebase dynamicLink suddenly not working

Tags: ios, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm manage Firebase dynamicLink to open our company app, suddenly from yesterday this is stop working, I have a custom domain and everything setup correctly, the subdomain is connected in firebase console and in the Xcode under associated domain, any idea ?

Thanks.